# Sencha touch, open weblinks in a new browser window

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

How can I make all the weblinks in my Sencha touch project open in a new browser window? The problem is that each time someone taps on a link, they are opened in the same embedded browser in which the app is running and there is no way to go back to the app.
For example, if I have a support page hyperlinked via  tag in a label, let's say

```
<a href="support.com>Help me!</a>
```

When the user taps on Help me, the support page opens in the app itself and there is no way to go back to the app!

EDIT:- I am testing with android device

Comment: Does adding target="_blank" to the tag do the same?

Comment: @mindparse yes, even after adding _blank target

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
 <a href="#" onclick="var ref = window.open('http://support.com', '_system'); return false;">support.com</a>
```

I think you should have the InAppbrowser cordova/phonegap plugin installed to get it working on this way.